# Best practice for getting "If not foo" conditionals

Tags: conditionals, best-practices

So, here are two ways you might set things up such that `\dostuff` is done when `foo` is false.

#### The "new conditional" method

If you know when `foo` is going to be set, then after that do:

```
\newif\ifnotfoo
\iffoo\notfoofalse\else\notfootrue\fi
```

And then use the `\ifnotfoo` test.

```
\ifnotfoo\dostuff\fi
```

#### The "else" method

Whenever you need to `\dostuff`, just do:

```
\iffoo\else\dostuff\fi
```

Is either method recommended over the other? If so, why? (Or is there another method which is even better?

Comment: The first is really inferior, because it needs an additional assignment. So for instance, it can't be used in expandable contexts. As a third alternative, there is `\unless\iffoo`.

Comment: AFAIK there is also an `\unless` primitive in e-TeX which negates a following `\if...`. Then you still can use `\else` as well.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Hard to comment on efficiency (one of your tags) without knowing more context. `\footrue` and `\foofalse` are really each just a `\let`. So if the *only* reason that this token is let to one definition or another is so that you can decide whether or not to "do stuff" then you don't need the if token at all, then you don't need the test.

Just define

```
\def\foofalse{\let\dostuff\realstuff}
\def\footrue{\let\dostuff\relax}
```

then you can replace the `\iffoo` construct with simply

```
 \dostuff
```

and it will either do nothing or the real definition depending on whether `\foofalse` or `\footrue` was most recently executed. Since this saves expanding `\iffoo` and skipping over the conditional text it is more efficient in principle but whether the difference is measurable on modern machines I haven't checked. It is unlikely that any of these make any real difference unless you do (literally) millions of tests.

Answer (score 5):

You asked for a *"better"* method. I find the method using the package [ifthen](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/ifthen.pdf) (thanks to [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) :-)) quite easy to read and to adapt.
Take a look:

```
\ifthenelse{\NOT \boolean{foo}}{\dostuff}{}
```

(no idea about efficiency, though)

The empty braces at the end {} are the empty **else** option. You can leave them out and write simply
`\ifthenelse{\NOT \boolean{foo}}{\dostuff}`
if you leave an empty line after the command to avoid any unexpected result.